# Disable ajaxStart() on a second function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have 2 functions, `submit()` with `$.ajax` and `click()` with `$.post`. In the function with `$.ajax` I use `ajaxStart()` and `ajaxStop()`, but at `$.post` no. Example:

In submit:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#myform').submit(function() {

            $(this).ajaxStart(function() {
                    $('.notice').html('Send...');
                    $('#send').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            });

            $(this).ajaxComplete(function() {
                    $('#send').removeAttr('disabled');
            });

            $.ajax({   
                  type: "POST",   
                  url: 'server01.php',   
                  data: $(this).serialize(),   
                  success: function(data) {   
                        switch(data){
                            case 'success':
                                $('.notice').html('Good!');
                                setTimeout("location.reload();",3000);
                                break;
                            default:
                                $('.notice').html('Error');
                                break;
                        }  
                  } });
    return false; 
    });

});
```

In click:

```
$(function() {

    $('#language').click( function() {
            $.post("language.php", { language: $(this).attr('class') } )
            .success(function(data) { location.reload(); })
            .error(function() { alert("error"); });
            return false;
    });

});
```

The problem is that when I run the `click()` function activates the `ajaxStart()` method on submit event.

There is a possibility to disable `ajaxStart()` or not to run when I use the click function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a possibility to disable ajaxStart(), because it works globally for the whole code.

but if you want to isolate what you coded for your myform element, you can do something like this :

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {

            $('.notice').html('Send...');
            $('#send').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

            $.ajax({   
                  type: "POST",   
                  url: 'server01.php',   
                  data: $(this).serialize(),   
                  success: function(data) {   
                        switch(data){
                            case 'success':
                                $('.notice').html('Good!');
                                setTimeout("location.reload();",3000);
                                break;
                            default:
                                $('.notice').html('Error');
                                break;
                        }  
                  },
                  complete : function() {
                      $('#send').removeAttr('disabled');
                  }
                 });
    return false; 
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also add the "global" option to the ajax request that you do not desire the ajaxStart to be triggered on. This disables all global Ajax event handlers on this request.

A [list of Ajax events disabled](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events) when using "global: false"

```
$.ajax({   
    type: "POST",
    global: false,
    url: 'server01.php',   
    data: $(this).serialize(),   
    success: function(data) {   
        switch(data){
            case 'success':
                $('.notice').html('Good!');
                setTimeout("location.reload();",3000);
                break;
            default:
                $('.notice').html('Error');
                break;
        }  
    }
```

});